# Is it possible to serialize transient field of the class using my custom serialization or using Externalization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, transient

Is it possible to serialize transient field of the class using my custom serialization or 
using Externalization?

Example: there is a class `Person` having name field transient

```
transient String name;
```

Is it possible to serialize it using below methods?

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

Comment: So what happens when you try doing that?

Comment: It is not giving exception while serialization but giving exception during deserialization.

Comment: Have u overriden readObject as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes if you are using the custom serializaton. When we do custom serialization by overriding the `writeObject` method, you take control of the serialization and can do whatever you want. So you can also assign or use a value of a `transient` field and can also marshall it along with other class attributes.

Comment: Can you explain how custom serialization is different from external serialization i.e externalizable?

Comment: Classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods with these exact signatures:

 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
     throws IOException
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
 private void readObjectNoData()
     throws ObjectStreamException;

Comment: I have read both of this. But I cant understand . Isn't custom serialization is similar to externalizable? Because in this we are writing our own code to serialize and vice versa

Comment: In earlier version of Java, reflection was very slow, and so serializaing large object graphs (e.g. in client-server RMI applications) was a bit of a performance problem. To handle this situation, the java.io.Externalizable interface was provided, which is like java.io.Serializable but with custom-written mechanisms to perform the marshalling and unmarshalling functions (you need to implement readExternal and writeExternal methods on your class). This gives you the means to get around the reflection performance bottleneck.

Comment: writeObject and readObject method serialize the non-serialized field. But, transient variables are never serialized in java.

Comment: @Juned thanks.that was the answer i was looking for.can you provide any link to read?

Answer (score 0):

You can write / read any fields including transient in writeObject / readObject. However it does not make much sense to first hide a field with transient then simply write / read it with custom serialization. Usually transient fields are not serialized at all or need some special processing with custom serialization.

As for Externalization it ignores transient, all fields are written / read explicitly.

Comment: Can you explain how custom serialization is different from external serialization i.e externalizable?

Comment: With Externalizable you save / restore all data yourself, with custom serialization you still can use defaultWriteObject / defaultReadObject, externalizable requires a public no-arg constructor...